# How to make table of contents like on Wikipedia using HTML

Tags: html

I would like to make a table of contents block on HTML like the one used on Wikipedia. I was thinking of just making a block and adding hyperlinks but I thought maybe there was an easier way. Can you please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but if you want a table of contents then couldn't you use a table?

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
a {color: black; text-decoration:none; font-weight:400;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Table of Contents</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Cool Stuff</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Other Stuff</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">See it's</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">A table</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Content</a></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">With links and style</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```